# Change an application's default activity programatically without AndroidManifest?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an application wherein when the user first open's the application he is asked to login with his credentials. So this activity say "Register" is the default activity. But once the user has logged in I want the default activity to change to some other activity say "MainActivity" from there on.

So how can i achieve this programatically?

I know one approach is to create a blank activity and based on a flag to launch the desired activity. Is there any other approach other than this ? And is the previous approach efficient ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is efficient, how ever you dont have to create a new blank activitiy, rather just use your mainActivity and if the user is not registered spawn off the Register activity cause that activity is only going to happen once. and the normal usecase is to stay in main activity.

that is how most people do it:) hope this helps

Comment: but for curiosity is there any way to change the default activity programatically ?

Comment: no there is no way to change the default activity cause the system looks at the manifest to know which one to start

Comment: if i call the register activity in onCreate() method of mainActivity i'm still able to see glimpse of mainActivity() before register activity is invoked. Do i need to perform this check somewhere else ?

Comment: no but you should finnish the main activity with this. finnish if i am not mistaken,  commentung from phone now